# Android - Primary key ID starts with 1000 using Room DB

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am new on Room Database and I am trying to implement a table that is autogenerated but it starts on 1000.

Here is my code.

```
@Entity(tableName = "sample_table")
data class SampleTable(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "sample_id")
    val sampleID: Long = 1000.toLong(),

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sample_date")
    val sampleDate: String? = null
)
```

I changed the default value to 1000 and still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to use an Entity with a 2nd constructor such  as :

```
@Entity(tableName = "sample_table")
class SampleTable {

        @PrimaryKey
        @ColumnInfo(name = "sample_id")
        var sampleID: Long? = null
        @ColumnInfo(name = "sample_date")
        var sampleDate: String? = null

        constructor ()

        @Ignore
        constructor(sample_id: Long) {
            sampleID = sample_id
        }
}
```

- `autoGenerate` (which equates to AUTOINCREMNET) is largely irrelevant as a column defined with INTEGER (Long) PRIMARY KEY will, if no value is specified generate an id that is one greater than the last value.

You would then, when inserting the very first row, use the second constructor and pass the required start value (1000). Subsequently you would use the initial constructor.

- without `autoGenerate` IF CAREFUL you could insert any value if it does not already exist. (not tested).

---

**Example App** that demonstrates the use of the above

The **SampleTable** @Entity class (normal class rather than a data class) is as above.

The @Dao interface **SampleTableDao** is :-

```
@Dao
interface SampleTableDao {
    @Insert
    fun insertSingleSampleTable(sampletable:SampleTable)
    @Insert
    fun insertManySampleTables(sampletables:List<SampleTable>)
    @Query("SELECT count() FROM sample_table AS count")
    fun getSampleTableRowCount(): Long
    @Query("SELECT max(sample_id) FROM SAMPLE_TABLE AS maxid")
    fun getMaxSampleTableId(): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM sample_table")
    fun getAllSampleTables(): List<SampleTable>
}
```

The @Database abstract class **SampleTableDatabase** is

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(SampleTable::class),version = 1)
abstract class SampleTableDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getSampleTableDao(): SampleTableDao
}
```

The testing Activity is

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val db1 = Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, SampleTableDatabase::class.java, "sample_table.db")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()
        val dao = db1.getSampleTableDao()
        // Add the first SampleTable row with an ID of 1000
        if (ifNoSampleTableRows(dao) == true) insertFirstSampleTable(dao,"2021-03-31")
        val stnormal = SampleTable()
        stnormal.sampleDate = "2021-04-01"
        dao.insertSingleSampleTable(stnormal)
        Log.d("TESTIT",
                "Number of SampleTable Rows is " + dao.getSampleTableRowCount())
    }

    fun ifNoSampleTableRows(dao: SampleTableDao):Boolean {
        return dao.getSampleTableRowCount() < 1
    }

    fun insertFirstSampleTable(dao: SampleTableDao, date: String) {
        val sampleTable = SampleTable(1000)
        sampleTable.sampleDate = date
        dao.insertSingleSampleTable(sampleTable)
    }
}
```

When first run (or after uninstall) the log has

```
D/TESTIT: Number of SampleTable Rows is 2
```

Using DB Explorer then :-

[image]

Running a second time (no uninstall) then

```
D/TESTIT: Number of SampleTable Rows is 3
```

and

[image]